# Invoking the .bat file by passing arguement from vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

From Vb.Net Application, i am calling .bat file by passing SourceFile , DestinationFile. The .Bat file transfers source file to the destination folder. If i call .bat file directly from command prompt by passing arguements, file is getting transfered.

My code fails to transfer the file. I am not able to find the error where the code fails to execute the .bat file.

```
 Dim strBatchFile As String = String.Empty

        strBatchFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
        strBatchFile = strBatchFile.Replace("\bin\Debug", "\ShellScript")
        strBatchFile = strBatchFile & "callsfxcl.bat"

        Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = strBatchFile
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0},{1}", strSourceFile, sSFTP)
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        proc.Start()
```

Comment: You should not separate arguments by commas on the command line, and also if either has spaces make sure to quote them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files are run by cmd.exe. `cmd /c batfile.bat`. If you had of set UseShellExecute to true Windows would have done it for you. I suspect you didn't read the error.

From .NET help fror filename property.

The set of file types available to you depends in part on the value of the UseShellExecute property. If UseShellExecute is true, you are able to start any document and perform operations on the file, such as printing, with the Process component. When UseShellExecute is false, you are able to start only executables with the Process component.

Comment: I did that. Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True will allow us ( User ) to run the .bat file. .Bat file window will pop-up as a small window, where i have to click RUN. Though, values are not transferred to Destination Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are run by cmd.exe.

```
cmd /c batfile.bat.
```

So `cmd` is your process and `/c c:\path\batch.bat` is your arguments.

Comment: could you please mention exactly where i need to do the changes. I tried your syntax from cmd as well as changing the value in the strBatchFile variable. I couldnt get the output.  /C is not recognized as an internal or external command.